# openpyxl - read data validation - list

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have an excel sheet, with data validation property - list.

I need to make a dictionary of column_name and associated drop down list values.

For e.g: {A:[a1, a2, a3], B:[b1, b2], C:[c1, c2, c3, c4]}.

There are multiple examples of how to embed data validation list in the excel, 
But how do I read it?

I have tried the simple code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

excel = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
sheet = excel.get_sheet_by_name('RequiredFormat')
for row in sheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
    input("Proceed ?")
```

And I checked for the options available for the cell.

But there is nothing that says data validation or lists.

Is there a way?

Comment: This looks like an attempt to provide application-like functionality. openpyxl particularly is concerned only with the file format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not read existing data validation currently. Read **Openpyxl** [documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/validation.html)

Comment: Well, that's no longer entirely true but it wouldn't help you much as, as with all formulae in openpyxl, they're never evaluated. But it would probably be possible to see there was a validation for a particular cell.

Comment: It looks like there is some reading functionality now: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/827/range-of-data-validation-changed-after

Answer (score 1):

As @Jeanne Lane points out in a comment, there is some ability to read data validation:

https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/827#note_124765

```
for dv in worksheet.data_validations.dataValidation:
    # dv.type has the type, and other things here....
```

Answer (score -2):

here is a snapshot of code I'm about to use to read the list values and for which cell

```
                tstlst = ws.data_validations.dataValidation
                print('---')
                print(tstlst)
                print('---')
                nr = 0
                for tst2 in tstlst:
                    nr += 1
                    print(str(nr) + " : " + str(tst2))
                    tst3 = tst2.sqref
                    print('sqref: ' + str(tst3))
                    tst4 = tst2.formula1
                    print('list: ' + tst4)
```

maybee this is helpfull

This produces following output for a datavalidation list I have in A13

2 : <openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidation object>
Parameters:
sqref=<MultiCellRange [A13]>, showErrorMessage=True, showDropDown=None, showInputMessage=True, allowBlank=False, errorTitle=None, error=None, promptTitle=None, prompt=None, type='list', errorStyle=None, imeMode=None, operator=None, formula1='"val1,val2,val3"', formula2=None

sqref: A13

list: "val1,val2,val3"